# Displaying dropdown in React Antd Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
                    const bands = this.props.ApplicationContainer.bands;
                    if(bands)   {
                        var bandsHtml = '<Select defaultValue="Select"><Option value="Select">Select</Option>';
                        const listItems = bands.map(function(obj) { 
                           const rObj = {};
                           rObj[obj.id] = obj.band;
                           bandsHtml += '<Option value="'+obj.band+'">'+obj.band+'</Option>';
                           return rObj;
                        });
                        bandsHtml += '</Select>';
                    }   else    {
                        var bandsHtml='';
                    }
                    console.log(bandsHtml);
                return (
                    bandsHtml
                );
```

The function returns what goes into the Table, but please check out this image:
https://ibb.co/jNBYnk

It displays as HTML in the cell. Any ideas on how it could be rendered as a Select in the Antd Table?

Comment: The select is a component, so lose the " ' " so it's just var bandsHtml = <Select ... >

Comment: Can you please send me the code... I am working on Antd table where I want to add dropdown with the cells.. i follow this link - https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-row

Answer (score 0):

```
let bandsHtml = null
if(bands)   {
    bandsHtml =
        <Select defaultValue="Select">
            <Option value="Select">Select</Option>
            {bands.map( (obj,index) => (<Option value={obj.band} key={index}>{obj.band}</Option>)}
        </Select>
}
```

/de SM0XLK ;-)